# Isometric embedding of $L^2$ onto $H^{-1}$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Many sources in the literature identify $L^2(X)$ with $H^{-1}(X)$ through the identification
$$ \varphi: L^2(X) \to H^{-1}(X); \quad \quad \varphi(u)(v) := (u,v)_{L^2}, \quad \quad v \in H^{1}_0(X).$$ 
Clearly, by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$ \| \varphi(u) \|_{H^{-1}} = \sup_{ \|v\|_{H^{1}_0} \leq 1 } | \varphi(u)(v)| = \sup_{ \|v\|_{H^{1}_0} \leq 1 } \big| (u,v)_{L^2} \big|  \leq \|u\|_{L^2}. $$ 
However, to show that it is an isometry, one also needs to show that

> $$ \| \varphi(u) \|_{H^{-1}}  \geq \|u\|_{L^2}.$$

I have trouble seeing this. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you define $L^2(X)$ and $H^{-1}(X)$ for a *Banach space* $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true, $\varphi$ is usually not an isometry. By the Rellich-Kondrachov compactness theorem, $\varphi$ is a compact map. Since the involved spaces are infinite-dimensional, $\varphi$ cannot be an isometry.